# DefaultCredentials option and HTTPS in MVC4 WebApi?

Tags: rest, asp.net-mvc-4, https, asp.net-web-api

I have a problem with DefaultCredentials option and HTTPS. If I use HTTP protocol everything is ok - ntlm authorization is ok, but if I change HTTP to HTTPS on webservice side in the Thread.CurrentPrincipal I have nothing (empty strings and IsAuthenticate on false value).
Do you have similar problem?

**My Ntlm configuration:**

```
internal class NtlmSelfHostConfiguration : HttpSelfHostConfiguration
{
    public NtlmSelfHostConfiguration(string baseAddress) : base(baseAddress) { }

    public NtlmSelfHostConfiguration(Uri baseAddress) : base(baseAddress) { }

    protected override BindingParameterCollection OnConfigureBinding(HttpBinding httpBinding)
    {
        httpBinding.Security.Mode = HttpBindingSecurityMode.Transport;
        httpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;
        return base.OnConfigureBinding(httpBinding);
    }
}
```

**HttpClient creation**

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true };
httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
```

User-Password Basic authentication is working correctly, so it isn't problem with certificates